# Creating Generic View Components with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, html-helper

I want to write my own custom HTML helper that extends an existing helper. E.g. I want to create to extend `@Html.EditorFor` like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.percent, new { data_a_sign="%", data_p_sign="s" })
```

Becomes:

```
@Html.PercentEditorFor(model => model.percent)
```

How would one go about writing that?

Something like this?

```
namespace AdminPortal.Helpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString PercentEditorFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper html, 
            Expression<Func<TModel>> expression)
        {
            // Some Magic?
        }
    }
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of returning the existing EditorFor method from your own helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PercentEditorFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper html, 
            Expression<Func<TModel>> expression)
        {
            return html.EditorFor(...);
        }
```

Put your own modified parameters into the EditorFor method. No magic required :)

Comment: Thanks, but I think I've misunderstood my problem. I want to add custom class and data attributes to the input generated by `@Html.EditorFor`, but when I add those attributes they are ignored by the template.

Comment: I've asked the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742488/how-to-add-custom-data-attributes-and-classes-to-html-editorfor