# How to add custom data attributes and classes to `@Html.EditorFor`?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, razor-2

I want to add some custom attributes to the `input` generated by `@Html.EditorFor`, I tried the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Percent, new { @class = "percent" })
```

But it just ignores my class, from what I can tell from searching around is that the template doesn't support adding custom attributes.

But how does one create a custom template adding support for the custom attributes, while keeping all the functionality of the old template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set the class attribute to Html.EditorFor in ASP.NET MVC Razor View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559028/set-the-class-attribute-to-html-editorfor-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the following posts, this question has been asked before on Stackoverflow.

- [Add css class to Html.EditorFor in MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789512/add-css-class-to-html-editorfor-in-mvc-2)
- [Set the class attribute to Html.EditorFor in ASP.NET MVC Razor View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559028/set-the-class-attribute-to-html-editorfor-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view)
- [ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor - Adding class to EditorFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576209/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-adding-class-to-editorfor)

There are many more examples, just `Google` it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Using jQuery this could be done easily

```
$("input").addClass("class-name")
```

Input tag

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)
```

For DropDownlist u can use following code

```
$("select").addClass("class-name")
```

for Dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownlistFor(model=>model.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is incorrect.

Html.EditorFor ignores custom css class
This behavior is by design.

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/223

Answer (score 0):

Try This it works for MVC3

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Percent)

<style type="text/css">

#Percent
{

   width:100%;

}

</style>
```