# How can I add min and max attributes to EditorFor input element?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, attributes

I have an `EditorFor` razor defined input box that sets the value for "Hours" that has it's data model bound:

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Hours, null, "weeklytargets[" + item.WeeklyTargetId + "].Hours")
```

When it's spit out to HTML it looks like so:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Hours must be a number." id="weeklytargets_17__Hours" name="weeklytargets[17].Hours" type="number" value="10">
```

How can I add attributes min and max for this input box of type number?

Comment: ```EditorFor``` will try to find a template based on ```item.Hours``` datatype or uihints etc. If you know what sort of form element you want to render. A quick way would be ```Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Hours, new { type="number", min="0", max="100" })```. Alternatively, you might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742488/how-to-add-custom-data-attributes-and-classes-to-html-editorfor#answer-17743013

Answer (score 2):

Try using the additionalViewData parameter to pass in htmlAttributes. This way you can specify a min and max value:

```
@Html.EditorFor(
    expression: modelItem => item.Hours,
    templateName: null,
    htmlFieldName: "weeklytargets[" + item.WeeklyTargetId + "].Hours",
    additionalViewData: new
    {
        htmlAttributes = new
        {

            min = 0,
            max = int.MaxValue
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.years_completed, new { @type="number", min = "1", max = "10" })
```